# Website doesn't show-up after S3 and Route 53 configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

According to AWS documentation:

1. I added 2 buckets for my website. (one for route and one for subdomain
   (example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).

   1a) I added my website files in both buckets.
2. Named the buckets according to my domain name.
3. I made all the files public and there is a red box that says publically accessible and I added this bucket policy.

```
 {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": "*",
                    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName.com/*"
                }
            ]
    
    }
```

Both buckets have static website hosting enabled.
I also selected index.html and error.html files.

**Now, this is important imo, when I click bucket website endpoint link, it perfectly shows my website.**

--
On the other hand, in **Route 53** where I have my domain.
I added 2 records for those buckets, everything is according to documentation AWS provides.

So, I selected my hosted zone, bucket names are matching with the domain name.
I created records
First one is for the root domain so I left the namespace blank.
Record Type : A Routes Traffic to IPv4 and some AWS resources
Alias: On
Route traffic to
Alias to S3 webstie end point.
Region: Same as bucket region
S3 endpoint (it automatically suggests to choose and it tells me that it's the exact bucket I want. So I select that).

I do the same for other bucket the only difference is that I add www for the namespace.

The tests working fine...

And from now on I am lost because I did everything according to documentation and everything seems like configured well. But when I go to my link, it doesn't show my webpage.

Comment: Where did you purchase the domain name? Was it on Amazon Route 53, or from some other site? If it is from another site, did you configure that site to use the Route 53 nameservers? Please tell us more about how you obtained/configure the domain name.

Comment: My domain is from Google Domains and I added mx records to my DNS settings. I also use google workspace and I added email records to my Amazon Route 53, so I'm able to send and receive emails to my domain through AWS.

I just contacted to Google Support to verify if mx records enough to see my website on AWS servers, and they told me it's all I need...

Comment: [MX records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) point to mail servers. They are not relevant to your question.

Comment: sorry, my bad.
I added Mx records for mail... For the webpage I added NS records to my DNS settings in Google.

Comment: Where did you get the NS records that you configured on the Google Domain? Also, what happens if you try to resolve the domain name (eg `nslookup` or even just use `ping` to display the IP address). If you do that, is an IP address displayed?

Answer (score 2):

To use a custom domain with an Amazon S3 bucket, you will need to **configure the domain (on Google Domains) to use the Route 53 nameservers**. This will allow Amazon Route 53 to resolve names within that domain.

Note that any DNS configuration on Google Domains, such as CNAME, A and MX records, will no longer be used. You would need to configure them on Amazon Route 53.

For step-by-step instructions, [How To: Connecting Google Domains to Amazon S3 | by Michelle | Medium](https://medium.com/@limichelle21/connecting-google-domains-to-amazon-s3-d0d9da467650)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I've mistaken in my previous comment. I already configured these records (long time ago). But still cannot see the webpage.

Comment: this document is for Domains Beta so I don't see that option in my Manage domains  page